# Excel VBA Userform checkbox questions

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

Is it possible to make it so that if a check is put in a check box that certain fields of the form are made so that the user cannot add data?

Form is asking for address, city, state, zip

Checkbox asks if the person is homeless

So wanting to make it so that if there is a check in the box that address info cannot be entered.

Else... if there is data in the address fields AND the box is checked that an error appears on the screen.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

An example could look like that.

```
Private Sub chkHomeless_Click()
    If chkHomeless.Value Then
        With txtCity
            .Value = ""
            .Enabled = False
        End With
        With txtState
            .Value = ""
            .Enabled = False
        End With
    Else
        txtCity.Enabled = True
        txtState.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

You would need to add the code for the *third TextBox* and you might want to add a kind of *Question* if the textboxes should really be emptied when checking the box. Or you display in this case a kind of *error message* as you wrote in your post.